# How to get the results with subqueries using laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel

I have been trying to get the results using subqueries. I need to perform two subqueries but so far I haven't been able to get the results.

The following query yields the desired result:

```
SELECT x.responsible_cook_id, x.d
FROM (
    SELECT 
        responsible_cook_id, 
        count(*) d
    FROM orders 
    GROUP BY responsible_cook_id
    ORDER BY count(*)  ASC
) as x
WHERE x.responsible_cook_id IN (
    SELECT ID
    FROM users
    WHERE type = "cook" AND shift_active = 1
)
ORDER BY x.d;
```

So far I have tried using this approach to perform the same query via Eloquent:

```
$fSubquery = Order::select('responsible_cook_id, count(*) as d')->groupBy('responsible_cook_id')->orderByRaw('count(*) ASC');
        $sSubquery = User::where('type', 'cook')->where('shift_active', 1);

        $users = DB::table(DB::raw("({$fSubquery->toSql()}) as x"))
            ->mergeBindings($fSubquery->getQuery())
            ->whereRaw("x.responsible_cook_id IN {$sSubquery->toSql()}")
            ->mergeBindings($sSubquery->getQuery())
            ->select('x.responsible_cook_id, x.d')
            ->orderByRaw('ORDER BY x.d')->get();
```

There isn't any result returned by this last query. Is there any way to perform these subqueries and get the results?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't solve the question above but this stays as a piece of learning that sometimes when you let it go it just happens to work itself out and sometimes even help you.

Instead of doing 3 queries (2 subqueries + outter query) I was able to reduce all of it to only one query using Laravel's Eloquent

Here is what happened

```
 // Get all cookers that have an active shift
 $cookersWorking = User::where('type', 'cook')
   ->where('shift_active', 1)
   ->select('id')
   ->get();
```

After getting all the cookers that have an active shift I was able to get all the cookers that have the least amount of dishes to make:

```
// We will get the cooker that has the least orders to prepare
$cookerWithLessDishes = Order::select('responsible_cook_id', DB::raw('count(*) as d'))
    ->whereNull('end') // added this but is not in the original question
    ->whereIn('responsible_cook_id', $cookersWorking->pluck('id'))
    ->groupBy('responsible_cook_id')
    ->orderByRaw('count(*) ASC')
    ->first();
```

I think I was able to reduce this to two queries. If I'm wrong please correct me.

Happy coding